# Блокировать процесс пока не завершатся потоки/дочерние процессы

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++14, pthread

Есть такой код:

```
if(pid_t pid = fork()) // spawn child process
{
    // parent process
    LOG("Try to execute smth. in child process");
    return;
}
else
{
    // child process
    doWork();
    std::terminate();
}
```

Тут порождается дочерний процесс в котором выполняется некоторая работа. Где-то в другом месте(а именно в момент завершения процесса) есть такое:

```
// wait childern(some code may call fork())
const pid_t pid{::wait(nullptr)};
```

Здесь процесс ждет завершения дочерних процессов(которые нафоркались ранее). Так вот, все это удовольствие не работает вместе ключом [`-fsanintize=thread`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html). Код зависает на `wait`, потому что компилятор добавляет некоторые дочерние процессы, которые сами не завершаются.

Вопрос. Как добиться аналогичного поведения без `wait`? Чтобы задачи запускались асинхронно, и главный процесс ждал завершения этих задач в случае прекращения работы. Может при помощи потоков, а не процессов. Если бы у меня в распоряжении был Qt, я бы закидывал эти `doWork` в `QThreadPool` и он бы в декструкторе ждал завершения всех задач. Но Qt у меня нет, а есть C++14 и pthread. Может кто-то предложить какое-нибудь решение?

Comment: Писать на обычном Си и не морочить (прежде всего самому себе) голову.

Comment: @avp, окей как это слелать на си?

Comment: Я не отвечу, а просто спрошу:  генерация и обработка исключений может помочь легче решить вопрос?..

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, не представляю как. Нужно просто запускать асинхронные задачи, которые будут гарантированно завершаться.

Comment: я тоже сейчас не представляю  ( в новогодные дни трудно что то представлять...).  Но примерно так - в задаче1 где то  trow Some_type1();   a в задаче2  throw Some_type2();.  Главный процесс обрабатывает Some_type1  и в обработчике может еще обработать Some_type2.  Или же Some_type2()  вообше не нужен.  Я начинающий в С++,  поэтому находу не могу ответить - просто идея состоит в том, что  исключения бывют полезны когда  где то решаешь как должны завершаться процессы, которые, как вы сказали, уже нафоркались... Мне будет интересно подумать над этим через пару дней - просто идея нафоркалась...

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, очевидно же. Запоминаете `pid` всех процессов, завершения которых хотите дожидаться в массиве, затем в точке ожидания ищете `pid` возвращаемый `wait()` в этом массиве и если нашли "вычеркиваете" его. Как только массив стал пустым вы дождались всех желаемых.

Comment: Действительно, они еще не исправили запуск `addr2line` для получения информации о символах. Так или иначе, это не должно создавать проблем для `wait` так как его следует вызывать для ожидания завершения только тех дочерних процессов, которые вы сами запустили. А `terminate` стоит заменить на простой выход.

Comment: Я не знаю сишные языки, но в джаве можно создать чтото типа PriorityExecutor и использовать EventBus

Comment: А `std::terminate()`-то как тут оказалось???

Comment: Вы что-то недоговариваете. Ваше `wait` вызывается в цикле? Если да, то как выглядит этот цикл?

Comment: @AnT, сам не представляю зачем он там нужен. Без него все тоже норм работает. `wait` и правда находится в цикле, но вызывается лишь однажды, когда программа завершается. И зависает из за дочерних процессов thread sanitizer-а. Вызовы `wait` можно увидеть [здесь](https://github.com/yrHeTaTeJlb/nfstrace/blob/master/src/controller/signal_handler.cpp#L64), а `fork` [здесь](https://github.com/yrHeTaTeJlb/nfstrace/blob/master/src/filtration/dumping.cpp#L69). Но уверяю вас, все что имеет отношение к проблеме есть в вопросе

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb: Уверяю вас, что то, как организован *цикл* вызова `wait` имеет гигантское критическое отношение к проблеме. Но в вопросе этого нет.

Comment: @AnT, А что с ним не так? Программа зависает на первом и единственном вызове `wait`.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb: Интересно. А откуда взята информация о том, что причина этого явления заключается в том, что "компилятор добавляет некоторые дочерние процессы, которые сами не завершаются"? Даже если существуют некие дополнительные процессы, которые "не завершаются", все равно это никак не должно мешать `wait` ловить завершение *ваших* дочерних процессов. `wait` ведь ловит завершение одного любого дочернего процесса.

Comment: @AnT, пожалуй, к этому было бы справедливо приписать "но это не точно". Несколько раз подряд программа компилировалась и запускалась с ключом `-fsanintize=thread` каждый раз при вызове этого `wait` было 4 активных дочерних процесса. И `wait` висел там 10 минут(он бы и дальше висел, но tavis-ci просто убивал процесс). Стоило перекомпилировать программу без этого ключа, дочерний процесс был всего один и `wait` без проблем дожидался его завершения. Воспроизводимость 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Накидал на скорую руку, но, думаю, идея понятна.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class fork_storage
{
public:
    fork_storage() noexcept
    {
        m_pid = fork();
    }

    fork_storage(const fork_storage&) = delete;
    fork_storage& operator=(const fork_storage&) = delete;
    fork_storage& operator=(fork_storage&& rhv) = delete;

    fork_storage(fork_storage&& src) noexcept
    {
        m_pid = src.pid();
        src.reset();
    }

    ~fork_storage()
    {
        if (is_parent()) {
            wait();
        }
    }

    bool fail() const noexcept
    {
        return m_pid < 0;
    }

    bool is_parent() const noexcept
    {
        return m_pid > 0;
    }

    void reset() noexcept
    {
        m_pid = -1;
    }

    pid_t pid() const noexcept
    {
        return m_pid;
    }

    int wait() noexcept
    {
        int status = -1;
        if (is_parent()) {
            waitpid(m_pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        }
        reset();
        return status;
    }


private:
    pid_t m_pid;
};



std::mt19937 &random_gen()
{
    static std::mt19937 gen(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    return gen;
}




int main()
{
    std::vector<fork_storage> processes;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        fork_storage fork_obj;        
        if (fork_obj.fail()) {
            std::cerr << "fork error\n";
        } else {
            if (fork_obj.is_parent()) {
                std::string message = "process created: " + std::to_string(fork_obj.pid()) + "\n";
                processes.emplace_back(std::move(fork_obj));
            } else {
                for (auto &process: processes) {
                    process.reset();
                }
                processes.clear();
                std::chrono::seconds sec(random_gen()() % 5 + 1);
                std::string message = "child " + std::to_string(getpid()) + " paused: " + std::to_string(sec.count()) + " sec\n";
                std::cout << message;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(sec);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    while (!processes.empty()) {
        fork_storage &fork_obj = processes.back();
        if(fork_obj.is_parent()) {
            std::string message = "wait process: " + std::to_string(fork_obj.pid()) + "\n";
            std::cout << message;            
        }
        processes.pop_back();
    }    
}
```

http://rextester.com/LUZI37730

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать `std::thread`:

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <thread>        

void func1() //Функция для запуска в потоке
{
    std::cout << "Executing func1" << std::endl;
}

void func2(int x) //Еще одна функция с аргументом
{
    std::cout << "Executing func2 with x=" << x << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
  //Запускаем функции в отдельных потоках
  std::thread thread1 (func1);
  std::thread thread2 (func2,1);

  //Параллельно можем исполнять код в главном процессе    
  std::cout << "Execute some commands in main process" << std::endl;

  //Ждем завершения кода в потоках
  thread1.join();
  thread2.join();

  std::cout << "Thread execution completed" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Помимо этого для распараллеливания процесса можно использовать `std::async`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

//Некоторая задача которую мы будем выполнять асинхронно
template <typename RandomIt>
int parallel_sum(RandomIt beg, RandomIt end)
{
    auto len = end - beg; //определяем длину вектора
    if (len < 1000)
        return std::accumulate(beg, end, 0); //короткий вектор суммируем сразу
    //Рекурсивно запускаем parallel_sum для получения большего числа потоков
    RandomIt mid = beg + len/2;
    auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async, parallel_sum<RandomIt>, mid, end);

    int sum = parallel_sum(beg, mid);
    return sum + handle.get();
}

int main()
{
    //Для примера будем суммировать большой vector случайных чисел
    std::vector<int> v(100000);
    for (auto& e: v){
        e = std::rand();
    }
    //Для интереса сравним время выполнения суммирования вектора с помощью async: 
    auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "The sum is " << parallel_sum(v.begin(), v.end()) << '\n';
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t1-t0).count() << "msec\n";

    //и суммирование в одном главном потоке:
    t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t1-t0).count() << "msec\n";

}
```

У меня результат получился следующий:

```
The sum is 1746632618
9msec
17466326181msec
```

`std::async` - высокоуровневый инструмент, он не гарантирует, что код обязательно будет выполнен в отдельном потоке.

Далее привожу простейший пример управления потоками, хотя это уже совсем другая история, подчеркиваю, что это простейший пример, много еще надо решать, например совместное использование cout всеми потоками:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void func(const int i) { // Функция, исполняемая в потоках
    cout << "Thread N " << i << " created" << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<thread> thread_pool; //создаем пул потоков на основе вектора
    int threadNum = 10; //количество потоков
    for (int i=0; i < threadNum; i++) {
        thread_pool.push_back(thread(func,i)); //запускаем потоки
    }
    for (auto& t : thread_pool) {
        t.join(); //ожидаем окончание выполнения потоков
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не знаю сколько будет потоков. То есть объекты `std::thread` надо как-то накапливать и хранить. По мере завершения удалять. Вопрос в том, как это сделать проще всего

Comment: Ну тут уж можно создать массив, список, вектор или что угодно, в цикле создавать, в цикле присоединять, в цикле удалять их

Comment: Это я тоже догадался. Вопрос как это сделать. А именно в какой момент их удалять?

Comment: @koresh, а разницу между процессами, порождаемыми `fork` (в вопросе) и threads (в вашем ответе) вы понимаете?

Comment: Ну насколько я понял необходимо "Чтобы задачи запускались асинхронно, и главный процесс ждал завершения этих задач в случае прекращения работы. Может при помощи потоков, а не процессов" помоему то что нужно

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, добавил простейший пример управление потоками, не гарантирую оптимальность, но должно быть более менее понятно, как это дальше все делать

Comment: Прошу прощения, перемудрил маленько в прошлый раз: конечно же при использовании `std::vector::push_back` совершенно не обязательно и даже нежелательно создавать объекты используя new. Ответ исправил, так еще проще!